# Using BWToolkit programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, bwtoolkit

Xcode no longer supports ibplugins so I wonder if anyone has any experience using BWToolkit programmatically. Basically BWSplitView does everything I need (the introduction video on the website says it all) but I'm a bit lost on how to use the class.

Has anyone done it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the `BWToolkit` there a few key things that I noticed.

- `BWSplitView` is a subclass of `NSSplitView`. So it should have some
  methods similar (i.e init methods).
- `BWSplitView` does have an `init` method that lets it be used as a
  singleton.

So that being said (without trying any of this in Xcode), you should be able to create an instance of `BWSplitView` using it's super class, `NSSplitView` 's, init method. Then add it to your view.

Here is an example (again, untested):

```
BWSplitView *splitView = [[BWSplitView alloc] initWithFrame:[[theWindow contentView] bounds]];

NSTextView *textView1 = [NSTextView new];
NSTextView *textView2 = [NSTextView new];


[splitView addSubview:textView1];
[splitView addSubview:textView2];

[splitView adjustSubviews];

[[theWindow contentView] addSubview:splitView];

[textView1 release];
[textView2 release];
```

You may have to write some of your accessor methods to BWSplitView private methods.

Hope this helps.